# Unable to resolve linker error with Qt/C++/NMake - no argument specified with option '/LIBPATH:' (Qt 5.2.0/MSVC 2010)

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, nmake

This error started just recently and I haven't been able to make heads or tails of it (I'm pretty new to Qt and QMake).  I am using Qt 5.2.0 and Qt Creator 3.0.0 to compile my project.

I was having some compilation issues with QMake; when attempting to use jom I ran into the issue that it doesn't support parent directories with spaces in the directory name, so I switched to NMake.  Since then I've been getting these errors when I try to compile:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1146: no argument specified with option '/LIBPATH:'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x47a' Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2' Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
```

The only LIBPATH variable I can find in my makefiles is on lines that look like this:

```
LIBS = glu32.lib opengl32.lib gdi32.lib user32.lib qtmain.lib /LIBPATH: /LIBPATH:..\ProjectGUI ProjectGUI.lib /LIBPATH:C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\msvc2010_opengl\lib 
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\msvc2010_opengl\lib\Qt5Widgets.lib     
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\msvc2010_opengl\lib\Qt5Gui.lib C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\msvc2010_opengl\lib\Qt5Core.lib
```

These were the files autogenerated by Qt Creator.  Do I need to edit these lines? Can qmake read multiple LIBPATH declarations in the same block like that?

Answer (score 0):

> when attempting to use jom I ran into the issue that it doesn't
>   support parent directories with spaces in the directory name

Are you sure? Did you put the parent directory path in double quotes.If you are using Qt Creator then you must use QMake.

If you wish to use nmake then use Visual Studio for the project, An addon for the same is available on Qt website.

Comment: Yes, I did put the parent directory path in double quotes -- this appears to be a known (and unresolved) issue with Qt Creator, per [Bug report: jom cannot handle makefiles when parent directory has spaces](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-12296), which is why I switched to NMake.  I would very strongly prefer not to use VS for this project as we have had issues in the past with cross platform compatibility, and the majority of our existing codebase is in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

After a day or so of fighting with this, I seem to have resolved this in a fairly simple way.  I created a new project directory for the repository without any spaces in the directory name.  I am now able to compile.